# switch a theme different per user role

Tags: themes, customization

I plan to use the member plugin by Justin Tadlock

I wish to know if how could I, on the front side, auto switch to a theme according to a role status.. for example authors would have the site presented using theme 1 while editor would have the site presenter using theme 2

I would rather have 2 different theme rather than conditionals within one theme structure

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

There's `current_user_can( 'CAPABILITY' );` (see @Codex Users & Roles to find the appropriate cap for your targeted role), that you can use to determin what theme you want to display. You can also check for `is_user_logged_in()` if you just want to differentiate between non-logged in and logged in users. Then you have the [`switch_theme()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme) function. Just wrap it up in a plugin and add a function that you hook into `plugins_loaded` or something similar (not sure when the user info is ready). Then switch depending on the role. Sidenote: You can't do that from a themes functions.php file, as the first available hook is `after_setup_theme`.

Comment: thank you very much Kaiser, it makes sense that it must be done as a plugin for due to the init prb.. I will play with it and come back whether I'm successfull or encounter trouble... thank you again

Comment: What happens if two different users visit the site simultaneously, with separate them settings? Does wordpress simply display the correct theme on the fly to the right user?

Comment: @LuckyLuke I have never tried switching themes on a per user basis, but as every request is normally a separate PHP process on the server, it should not be a problem regarding the request itself. No idea without testing if it has implications and sideeffects in the database as this function [switches options](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L677) on the fly. Could easily be that this messes up your database as it is not necessarily in sync regarding timing. I _think_ it won't really work well and caching might have impact as well.

Comment: @kaiser thanks for clarifying, you have discouraged me from following this path :)